# Maui splash screen is not scaled correctly

Tags: maui

I'm building a Maui mobile app (android and ios). I have a problem, that my splash screen is not scaled correctly. I have defined it this way in the project csproj file:

```
<MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Images\splashscreen.png" Color="#66B3FF" BaseSize="512,512" />
```

File format is png and size 482 x 482. The image should be scaled down to fit the screen, but it's cropped at the sides. I have tried with different BaseSize values. The parameter seems to have no effect at all. How can I resize the image to fit the screen? Is there an error in my configuration or is there a bug in Maui?

**Edit:**
Alternatively, is it possible to disable the default splash screen and use a completely custom, xaml based splash screen in maui?

[image]

Comment: Known problem. Adjust the scaling yourself.

Comment: Would you have a link to a github issue? Could you elaborate, how to adjust the scaling?

Answer (score 0):

There is an existed issue about [MauiSplashScreen resizetizering issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11160)  on the github.

And according to [the workaround in it](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11160#issuecomment-1307939002), the image will be resize in the Maui Prject which target is .net 7.0.
So you can try to use the .net 7.0 and add the Resize = "true" in the .csproj such as:

```
<MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Images\splashscreen.png" Color="#66B3FF" BaseSize="512,512" `Resize = "true"`/>
```

In addition, I have created a new project and set the splash image as a png file which size is 482 x 482. And the image showed correctly.

Comment: For me, Resize parameter seems to make no difference on iOS or Android. What is different when making a new project, if it works there?

Comment: In the link I provided, the Resize parameter will work in the .net 7.0. And in the .net 6.0, it will make no difference. In addition, the 482 x 482 png file shows correctly in my project. Can you show a picture about **it's cropped at the sides** you siad? @wekso

Comment: My project targets .net 7.0, still no difference. Unfortunately I can't share the logo, but I'll update the question with an image, that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Did you test with another png file? I can't make sure the problem is a bug or only because the special image file. @wekso

Comment: In addition, the picture in the question showed that the splash image was over the size of the screen. Right? @wekso

Comment: Yes, that's right. It should be scaled down to fit the screen.

Comment: Sorry, my careless. You can put it in the `Resources\Splash\splashscreen.png` 
 not the `Resources\Splash\splashscreen.png`. The Splash folder is used to storage the splash images. @wekso

Comment: Did it work correctly now? @wekso

Comment: Nope, still same issue after moving the image to Splash folder. If I scale the image with some image editing program, the image fits the screen. So I assume the same happens with a different image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251943/discussion-between-liyun-zhang-msft-and-wekso).